# Redirect Loop on Symfony security

Tags: php, symfony

Im just new to Symfony. So I have a task on my work to create a 
traditional login form. So I've created a firewall and access_control on my security.yml named main like so:

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    profiler1:
        pattern: ^/_profiler
        security: false
        anonymous: true

    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    gos_websocket:
        pattern: ^/channel
        security: false

    oauth_token:
      pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
      security:   false

    api_doc:
      pattern:  ^/api/doc
      security: false

    oauth_authorize:
      pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
      security:   false

    api:
      pattern:    ^/api
      fos_oauth:  true
      stateless:  true
      anonymous:  false

    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        #stateless: false
        #simple_preauth:
        #    authenticator: apikey_authenticator
        #provider: api_key_account_provider
        provider: ms.user_provider
        logout:
            path: /security/logout
            target: /security/login
        form_login:
            login_path: /security/login
            check_path: /security/check-login
            default_target_path: /dashboard
            always_use_default_target_path: true

   #anonymous: true

   # activate different ways to authenticate


   # http_basic: ~
   # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate


   # form_login: ~
   # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
access_control:
    #- { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    # - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/security/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

When I try to access the security/login URL it said that it encounters too many redirects? Why is that so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You missed an "s"

```
- { path: ^/security/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: still not fixed, why I did is to add anonymous: true on the firewall.